# Cardinality of set of Baire functions

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, cardinals, baire-category

I'm reading [this](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/37/0/93755/sur-les-types-d-ordre-des-ensembles-lineaires) paper of Sierpinski. At p.260 he says that it is well known that the set of all injective Baire functions (on the reals) is of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, but he gives no reference. Is there any reference for this result? Alternatively can you give me an hint on how to prove it?

Comment: What notion of Baire functions is this? On the reals or any Polish space?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma on the reals

Comment: And the definition ? pointwise limits of continuous functions?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The fact is that Sierpinski does not give the definition he employs, but I think is the one on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function

(of arbitrary class $\alpha$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There are $2^{\aleph_0}= \mathfrak{c}$ many real continuous functions (and certainly that many injective ones, say $x \to ax+b$ for $a \neq 0$).
- From a set functions of size $\mathfrak{c}$ we can form at most $\mathfrak{c}$ many pointwise limit functions, as $\mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$ etc.
- By induction it follows there are *at most* $\mathfrak{c}$ many Baire functions on $\Bbb R$.
- We already have the lower bound from injective continuous functions.

So Sierpiński's remark is rather trivial and bog standard (maybe less so in his time).

Comment: I was being aware of the answer while answering to your comments, and your answer is precisely what I was thinking about, thanks