# A question on Riemann integrable functions.

Tags: integration

Let $I$ be a non-empty closed bounded interval and $A$ be the set of differentiable functions $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f':I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is bounded.
Let $B$ be the set of functions $f$ in $A$ such that $f'$ is Riemann integrable over $I$.
It's known that the set $A -B$ is non-empty.

My question is

> What is the cardinality of  $A-B$?

Comment: I Think both have cardinalities of the continuum. $B$ for example contains the constant functions

Comment: I see but I am not sure about the cardninality of $A-B$. The question is edited a bit now.

Comment: $f_a'$ is Riemann integrable and hence it does not belong to $A-B$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: If $f \in A - B$, then so is $f + c$ for any constant $c$. So $A - B$ has cardinality at least the continuum.

Comment: @user920957, Oh that's true! You answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to my comment above let me also answer the related question of what is the cardinality of $A' - B'$, where $A'$ are the derivatives of the functions in $A$ and $B'$ are the derivatives of the functions in $B$.
In this case the solution above does not work.
However, the standard example of an $f \in A - B$ is [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function), constructed by $x^2 \sin(1/x)$ and a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).
Different choices of fat Cantor sets then gives nonequal Volterra functions with nonequal derivatives. Hence, since there are a continuum of fat Cantor sets, the set $A' - B'$ also has cardinality at least the continuum.

Comment: The cardinalities of all these sets is the continuum because all of these functions are Baire one functions (pointwise limit of continuous functions), and there are exactly continuum many Baire one functions because, for example, there are only continuum many continuous functions, and there are only continuum many infinite sequences of elements in a set of cardinality continuum -- $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}.$ In fact, even the MUCH larger collection **(continued)**

Comment: of Baire functions (= Borel measurable functions in this context) has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ -- see [Cardinality of set of Baire functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4269192/13130). For much stronger results (they trivially imply YES to the OP's question), see the mathoverflow question [Are “most” bounded derivatives not Riemann integrable?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/459470/15780).